# Two dependent spinners

Tags: android, spinner

The items of the first one are defined in xml (`<string-array>`) but the second one should present different items arrays of strings according what is selected on the first...

The possible array of strings for the seconds are fetch from a web service using an `AsyncTask` (This part is working). In my `onPostExecute(Void result)` I have this:

```
private class GetInfoTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(StateTabActivity.this);

    //...
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Log.d("StateTabActivity","onPostExecute");
        sectorsArray = getSectorsName(); // sectorsArray is an array of strings
        roomsArray = getRoomsName(); // roomsArray is an array of strings
        subcategorySpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(StateTabActivity.this, R.layout.my_spinner,sectorsArray);
        subcategorySpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        subCategorySpinner.setAdapter(subcategorySpinnerAdapter);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

On the `onCreate()` of my activity I have:

```
Spinner categorySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.statetab_category_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> categorySpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.my_spinner,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_category));
    categorySpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    categorySpinner.setAdapter(categorySpinnerAdapter);

    subCategorySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.statetab_subcategory_spinner);

    categorySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            Log.d("StateTabActivity","in onitemselected");
            switch (arg2) {
            case 0:
                    //I want to set here the items of sectorsArray to be displayed on the second spinner (subCategorySpinner)
                break;
            case 1:
                    //I want to set here the items of roomsArray to be displayed on the second spinner (subCategorySpinner)
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
```

So my question is: What should I do to bind the right array to the second spinner, according what is selected on the first one?

Answer (score 0):

This is my code to get district list as per selected state.

```
    final Spinner state = (Spinner)_activity.findViewById(R.id.state);
    final Spinner district= (Spinner) _activity.findViewById(R.id.district);
   _activity.findViewById(R.id.name_of_city);
    state.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

       @Override
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int i, long lng) {



            if(i == 0){
                districtAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>( _activity ,              android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, **DistrictList**.AndraPradesh); 
  //DistricList is another class.its code given below
                                          districtAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            district.setAdapter(districtAdapter);
                            if(_viewState == SAVED_VIEW){
                                                                                          district.setSelection(getArraySpinner(DistrictList.AndraPradesh,_initialValues.getAsString("District")),true);
            }
        }
```

In DistricList class,

```
public class DistrictList {
    public static final String[] AndraPradesh = new String[] {"Adilabad",
        "Anantapur",
        "Chittoor",
        "East Godavari",
        "Guntur",
        "Hyderabad",
        "Karimnagar",
        "Khammam"};
}



}
```